# Split String to data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to split a one-line text in R and store them in a dataframe.

For instance. A text like the following:

`hello-world;1|(good)night world;2|...`

Is expected to become:

```
V1    V2
hello-world    1
(good)night world    2
```

In order to achieve this: I start by splitting the initial text on '\'. For that reason, I use separate from `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(str) %>% separate(str, into=c("V1"), sep='\\|')
1 hello-world;1
#Warning message:
#Too many values at 1 locations: 1
```

I suspect in the first split the issue rises with the `-`. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this via `tidyverse` then you need to use `unnest` to make it long and then `separate` the values i.e.

```
libraary(tidyverse)

data.frame(v1 = 'hello-world;1|(good)night world;2|') %>% 
       mutate(v1 = strsplit(as.character(v1), '\\|')) %>% 
       unnest(v1) %>% 
       separate(v1, into = c('v1', 'v2'), sep = ';')

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#                 v1    v2
#*             <chr> <chr>
#1       hello-world     1
#2 (good)night world     2
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(tidyverse)

text <- c("hello-world;1|(good)night world;2")

df_text <- data.frame(a = unlist(strsplit(text, "|", fixed = T)))

df_split_text <- separate(df_text, a, c("V1", "V2"), sep = ";")
```

Answer (score 0):

We know @udden2903 has given the best answer with `tidyverse`, but this `base R` should work too.  Replace the `|` with `\n`, and then read using `read.table`

```
read.table(text=gsub("[|]", "\n", text), header = FALSE, sep=";", stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
#                 V1 V2
#1       hello-world  1
#2 (good)night world  2
```